# WSO2 Custom Grant Type with customized config properties

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, customization

I've followed the doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Writing+a+Custom+OAuth+2.0+Grant+Type

Now that I created my new Grant Type, I need do make it easy to config to each environment.

How can I add custom properties in a Custom Grant Type?

I need to use those properties to deploy the custom grant_type in distinct environments(production,QA, development, ...) without rebuilding the code.

For example, my Grant Type make a request to a REST Endpoint to validade the credentials, but this endpoint is different for each environment. (rigth now, my custimized grant type have those configuration properties hardcoded)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a project with custom **grant_type** you can add as many query parameters as you want to your request.

Because of this you can **add one custom parameter** for your environment and base on this parameter you can add a logic in your custom grant type project to make a separate call to the different REST Endpoints.

In the documentation that you followed a such custom query parameter that I suggest to use is  *mobileNumber=0333444*

**EDIT:**

Base on our communication I edit my first response.

***You can use  NetworkUtils.getLocalHostname() from org.wso2.carbon.utils jar library*** which will return *`HostName`* property from carbon.xml file.

Comment: I think this is not safe. A client can send the wrong parameter on purpose, receiving a valid token that was validated, for example,  in the development REST Endpoint and will be free to call prodution environment APIs.

Comment: To safe your product you have to implement some kind of validation of your parameters. If the validation process failed you shouldn't generate and return token. In this case you have to return some error.

Also your dev and QA environments should be in DMZ, not public. Also you will generate tokens for who? If you generate token for user you have to check if such user exist in your system based on combination of the system  parameter and user parameter (for example username or email).

Comment: What I need is a way do switch the configuration of my Grant_type without rebuilding the code. The client should not be responsable to request for the correct configuration.